# How to filter input using the new BasicTextField2 InputTransformation & TextFieldBuffer

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I'm creating a `BasicTextField2` for entering an IBAN like `DE02 1203 0000 0000 2020 51`.

Let's assume i'm only targeting german (DE) IBANs and thus am not interested in anything else except the digits:

```
@Composable
fun DigitOnlyTextfield(){
    BasicTextField2(
        state = rememberTextFieldState(),
        inputTransformation = DigitsOnlyTransformation,
    )                    
}
```

[The sample](https://proandroiddev.com/basictextfield2-a-textfield-of-dreams-2-2-fdc7fbbf9ffb) i found does this the easy way: "If a user enters something wrong, just revert everything"

```
object DigitsOnlyTransformation : InputTransformation {
    override val keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)

    override fun transformInput(
        originalValue: TextFieldCharSequence,
        valueWithChanges: TextFieldBuffer
    ) {
        if (!valueWithChanges.asCharSequence().isDigitsOnly()) {
            valueWithChanges.revertAllChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

However, i have a more complex usecase: pasting an already formatted IBAN should work (e.g. blanks, dashes, etc.).
What i basically need is something like `valueWithChanges.filter { it.isDigit() }`, which doesn't exist.

So i came up with the following (cumbersome) solution - is there any way to make this more elegant?

```
object DigitsOnlyTransformation : InputTransformation {
    override val keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)

    override fun transformInput(
        originalValue: TextFieldCharSequence,
        valueWithChanges: TextFieldBuffer,
    ) {
        val badIndices = valueWithChanges.asCharSequence().toList().indicesOf { !it.isDigit() }

        // reversed so we don't mess up indices we're iterating over
        badIndices.reversed().forEach {
            valueWithChanges.delete(it, it + 1)
        }
    }
}

/** returns the indices of all values selected by [selector]*/
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.indicesOf(selector: (T) -> Boolean): List<Int> =
    mapIndexedNotNull { index, t -> if (selector(t)) index else null }
```